# script to rename file

Tags: shell, file, rename

I am trying to write a script to batch rename files in a folder, exactly like this:

Filename:
LC PartA - PartB.pdf

shall become
LC PartB - PartA.pdf

So basically everything that is after the " - " shall be in front of the " - " and what is in front of the " - " shall go after the " - ", except of the first 3 characters ("LC ").

Anyone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. What have you tried? Why `rename` failed for your case? Use a simple `for i in *` loop with `mv` and `sed to filter the parts?

Comment: Sorry... I know that I have to do it with `for i in *` and `mv`, but I don't understand how to use `sed`

Comment: Sure! Have fun at https://regexcrossword.com/ to learn regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

I went for `find` with `while read`. `find` finds files that match the regex `LC <anything> - <anything>.pdf`. For each matching file, I switch the parts using sed and then call `mv`:

```
find . -type f -regex '\./LC .* - .*\.pdf' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/LC \(.*\) - \(.*\)\.pdf/LC \2 - \1 .pdf/')
    mv -v "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

For simplicity and when not handling some strange corcer-cases (like directories named the same way, ex.), you can go with a good old for:

```
for file in "LC "*" - "*".pdf"; do
    newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/LC \(.*\) - \(.*\)\.pdf/LC \2 - \1 .pdf/')
    mv -v "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

I have tested using [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/83tCcN)